# Automapper vs Dapper for mapping

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, automapper, dapper

This question is to verify if the current implementation is the right way to go about in terms of best practices and performance. So far in all my previous companies I have been using Auto Mapper to map relational objects to domain model entities and domain model entities to Dtos. The ORM tools have been Entity framework.
In my current company they are using Dapper as ORM tool and do not use AutoMapper as they say Dapper does the mapping for you internally. So the way they have structured the project is create a separate class library project that contains Dtos and reference the Dtos in Dataccess and Business layer. 
The query returned by Dapper is internally mapped to the Dtos. These Dtos are returned to the Business layer and so on.

For example

In the code below the Participant function is Dto.

**Repository file in DataAccess layer**

```
 public List<ParticipantFunction> GetParticipantFunctions(int workflowId)
        {
            // Update the Action for Participant
            string selectSql = @"SELECT [WFPatFunc_ID] AS WFPatFuncID
                        ,[WFFunction]
                        ,[SubIndustryID]
                        ,[DepartmentID]
                    FROM [dbo].[WF_ParticipantsFunctions]
                    WHERE [DepartmentID] = (SELECT TOP 1 [DepartmentID] FROM [dbo].[WF] WHERE [WF_ID] = @workflowId)";

            return _unitOfWork.GetConnection().Query<ParticipantFunction>(selectSql, new
            {
                workflowId = workflowId
            }).ToList();
        }
```

The reason what I have been told by the developers is that AutoMapper would be just an overhead and reduce speed and since Dapper does mapping internally, there is no need for it.

I would like to know if the practice they are following is fine and have no issues.

Comment: No, the followed practice is wrong because of below reasons:
1. Database query result must be fetched in Entity then converted to Dtos, we must  not fetch result directly into the Dto.
2. Dto and Entity both have different purpose, Dto can have different columns as compare to Entity.

Comment: I think that if they are using dapper and creating views and mapping to DTO's `Automapper` is an overhead. Since what `Automapper` is commonly used in mapping Entities with `DTO's/ViewModel`. If you think that the DTO'S that `Dapper` Map are not suitable to use them as a `ViewModel` then `AutoMapper` would be a good tool to create `ViewModels` "automagically"

Comment: We have an angular client and not MVC. These objects are passed to the web api before being sent to the client

Comment: @Tom if the DTO's are passed (assuming) in `json` and you don't need to manipulate or create a `ViewModel` I don't see where `Automapper` is helpful in this scenario.
@VijayRaheja I think fetch all the Entity and then covert them to DTO's is like the first step to start using it, but when you need more efficiency in queries and create one "DTO" to return, its better than fetch the entity and then convert to "DTO" and return

Comment: I thought as per design standards, the Dtos reside in the business layer and model entities in the dataaccess layer and they are mapped via Automapper. Here they have created Dto as a separate project and referenced in both data access and business layer. Is that alright.

Comment: "Is that alright" (?) - well: does it work? does it solve the problem that they need to solve without introducing worse problems? if so: ... yes!

Comment: Maybe the problem is the name `DTO's` why not just call them `TO's` :)

Comment: @jjchiw the "D" in "DTO" is not database - it is data. There is no requirement for DTOs to be specific to some data layer. These types clearly convey data, so... Heck, many DTOs are at the API boundary layer (right at the public edge) to describe serialization semantics.

Comment: @MarcGravell yes I understad, it was just semantic stuff..... "DTO" / Data(base) transfer object (no!), so just call it `TransferObject`, and forget about the Data(base), the DTO could be used in data or API boundary as you said and so the TO, and the ViewModel in Api boundary.....

Answer (score 20):

There *is* no right or wrong here. If the current system works and solves all their requirements, then great: use that! If you have an *actual need* for something where auto-mapper would be useful, then great: use that!

But: if you *don't* have a need for the thing that auto-mapper does (and it appears that they do not), then... don't use that?

Perhaps one key point / question is: what is your ability to refactor the code if your requirements change *later*. For many people, the answer there is "sure, we can change stuff" - so in that case I would say: defer on adding an additional layer until you actually have a requirement for an additional layer.

If you **will absolutely not** be able to change the code later, perhaps due to lots of public-facing APIs (software as a product), then it makes sense to de-couple everything *now* so there is no coupling / dependency in the public API. But: most people *don't have that*. Besides which, dapper makes no demands on your type model whatseover other than: it must look kinda like the tables. If it does that, then again: why add an additional layer if you don't need it?

Comment: What I found out recently is that Dapper can't map data to private complex object. It only works for primitive types. Do you know if that's true? I am trying to practice DDD, and most of the time my domain models don't look like the database tables, and most of time my domain models would have private setters with complex objects, and private constructors too. In that case, Dapper doesn't work that well.

Answer (score 12):

This is more of an architecture problem and there is no good or bad.

**Pros of DTOs:**

**Layering** - You are not directly using data object so you can use Attributes for mapping and stuff not needed in your UI. That way you can have the DTOs in a library that has no dependencies to your data access stuff.(*Note you could do this with fluent mapping but this way you can use what you like*)

**Modification** - If you domain model changes your public interface will stay the same. Lets say you add a property to the model all the stuff you already build wont be getting the new field in you JSON for no reason.

**Security** - This is why Microsoft started pushing DTOs if I remember correctly I think CodePlex(*Not 100% sure it was them*) was using EF entitles directly to add stuff to the database. Someone figure this out and just expanded the JSON with stuff that he was not allowed to access, for example if you have a post that has a reference to a user you could change the role of the user by adding a new post because of change tracking. There are ways to protect you self from this but security should always be an opt-out not opt-in.

I like to use DTOs when I need to expose BI level to a public interface. For example if I have an API that has System operations like **api/Users/AllUsers** or **api/Users/GetFilteredUsers**.

**No DTOs**

**Performance** - Generally not using DTOs will run faster. No extra step of mapping. Projections help with this but you can really optimize when you know what you need to do.

**Speed of development and smaller code base** - Sometime a large architecture is an overkill and you just want to get things done. And you are not just doing copy paste of your properties for most of you time.

**More flexibility** - This is opposite to the security sometimes you want to use the same api to do more then one thing. For example if you want to have the UI decide what it wants to see from a big object. Like select and expand. (Note this can be done with DTOs but if you ever tried to do expand with DTOs you know how tricky it can get)

I use it when I need to expose the data access level to the client, if you need to use Breeze or JayData and/or Odata. With api like **api/Users** and  **api/Users?filter=(a=>a.Value > 5)**