# C# Net Core: How to Implement Domain Layer with proper Entity Tracking

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

Our current architecture uses Net Core 3 with Entity Framework. It maps from Data Entities --> Domain --> DTO.

Currently, some people on the team want to remove the Domain Layer.
These are their points.

- "Doesn’t allow EF entity tracking because we would have 2 different model objects in memory for the same entity
- Cause issues when working on the second model object in memory as we have to remove the first from context

How can these issues be addressed properly while still utilizing Domain layer?

Comment: Data Entities means Data Access and Domain means Business Layer?

Comment: I think you need some code examples the question is way too broad. I answered something similar don't know if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775320/automapper-vs-dapper-for-mapping/44777367#44777367